# OpenMP without threads

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a problem with my cluster. I am working with an old system that has no threads (they are not implemented in my system). My question is simple: can I work in parallel with OpenMP without defining in the program the number of threads? I mean, using openMP with real cores.
If this is the case, I would like to know how to do it. I am working with Fortran 90.

Comment: Question does not compute. So you mean your system has only a single core? If yes why do you want to use omp to begin with?

Comment: I have never try it on a single core/thread CPU, but I think you can set the environmental variable OMP_NUM_THREADS to define the number of threads. In linux-like system, run the shell command export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2, before running your executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variable OMP_NUM_THREADS to specify how many threads you want to run. This will only work if the directives inside the program related to this, have not been specified.

If you want to compute between nodes, you should take a look at [MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/).

**WARNING**: if your system has only 1 core per node, you won't benefit from using several threads and it may even incur in performance degradation. Your only hope there is that the processor has multithreading enabled, but it won't be the same as multiple cores.

Comment: My real problem is that my system (with several cores) is quite old and has not threads implemented (the hardware is not adapted to them). So I cannot use sentences as "OMP_NUM_THREADS". My question is more related with the possibility of using openMP with real cores instead of threads.

Comment: OpenMP doesn't care if the threads it uses are real physical threads (one per core) or simulated (several threads per core aka multithreading). My second paragraph was intended as warning. I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: The specification of OpenMP is based on threads. If you don't have threading support in your OS, OpenMP will fail to compile. If it compiles, everything miguelbernardi wrote is true.

Comment: miguelbernardi: Last time I checked the OpenMP specification, **num_thread** had precedence over **omp_set_num_thread** which have precedence over OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable which have precedence over the XLSMPOPTS environment variable. Are you sure of what you said?

Comment: @Soravux Yes, you are right, I edited this answer so now is correct. Sorry I didn't see your comment until now.